# How to run IntelliJ tomcat server on https?

Tags: java, ssl, intellij-idea, ssl-certificate, csr

i need to test with Okta SSO which only allows https connection so how can i  run IntelliJ tomcat server on https?

I have configured the below on c drive tomcat server using below instructions but don't know how to setup ssl on intellij tomcat server?

**Done -**

Prerequisite :

---

1)JDK installed + JAVA_HOME environment variable setup

2. Tomcat 8.0 archieve file

---

Now open cmd :
run this command:

```
cd %JAVA_HOME%/bin
```

---

Step 1: Generating keystore file : .keystore

---

keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA

and save entered password : password1

---

Step 2: Now we will configure tomcat for using keystore file and -SSL config

---

-->now open server.xml file  and replace following :

```
<Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false"
    disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxThreads="25"
    port="8443" keystoreFile="C:\Users\Selva\.keystore" 
    keystorePass="password"
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https"
    secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

---

Step 3: Now we will configure our web app to run on
https.

---

-->open web.xml of web application.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>securedapp</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

---

Step 4: Test Run

Comment: See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006489639/comments/360000906820

Comment: @Andrey i saw that but it is not clear about any setup for https on intellij other than port number?

Comment: i am getting the below error "The Content Security Policy directive 'upgrade-insecure-requests' is ignored when delivered in a report-only policy."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the `keystoreFile="/Users/.keystore"` is specified correctly, see Tomcat [Troubleshooting](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Troubleshooting) section:

> By default, Tomcat expects the keystore file to be named `.keystore` in the user home directory under which Tomcat is running (which may or may not be the same as yours :-). If the keystore file is anywhere else, you will need to add a `keystoreFile` attribute to the `<Connector>` element in the Tomcat configuration file.

Comment: i am getting "Access to localhost was denied". How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same issue,
Solved by removing the ., u are not in Linux:

```
 keystoreFile="C:\Users\Selva\keystore"
```